# Proof that $| e^x-e^y|\leq | x-y|$ for $\Re(x), \Re(y) < 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying a proof in complex analysis which uses this estimation but does not prove it and I have been unsuccessful in trying to find a proof on the internet. My professor gave me a proof before christmas but I forgot some details. First he looked at the integral $\int_a^b e^z dz = e^b - e^a$. In my next line I have simply written a+t(b-a), a line, and then $\int_0^1 e^{a+t(b-a)}(b-a) dt = e^b - e^a$

What happens between the evaluation of the first integral and where I wrote the line? Are we applying some kind of transformation?

Comment: He's made the change of variables $z=a+t(b-a)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$f(b)-f(a) = \int_{\gamma}f^{'}(z)dz$$ where
$\gamma$ is a line segment $ta-(1-t)b$  and $t \in [0,1]$
one gets, sort of a mean value theorem for complex functions
$$|f(b) - f(a)| <= max_{t\in [0,1]}|f^{'}(ta + (1-t)b)|*|b-a|$$
The rest follows from the formula on $f(z) = e^{z}$ that is $f^{'}(z) = e^{z}$ and the fact that Re(x) < 0 and Re(y) < 0.

Note that the last assumption implies that Re(z) on the line segment above is negative as well.